# how to iterate dynamically over child elements using for in xquery

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I have a XML file which contains multiple XML documents. In large XML document each document has a root node and it is common for all the XML documents in that file. However the child elements inside the root name vary. I have to write a for loop to iterate dynamically each and every child node and have to show it on a table format. Here I have pasted my XML format below. I have multiple xml files in that way but the root node is common for every file. I want to map each child element as table row and data as table column. child elements numbers would vary

```
<source>
  <empname>john </empname>
  <empid>25825   </empid>
  <salary> 20000 </salary>
  <dob> 12-08-1993</dob>
</source>
<source>
  <empname>joe</empname>
  <empid>25826</empid>
  <salary>20000</salary>
  <dob>12-07-1993</dob>
<source>

<source>
  <emptype>developer</emptype>
  <address>3155 </address>
  <mobile>58258365</mobile>
</source>
<source>
  <emptype>analyst</emptype>
  <address>3155 </address>
  <mobile>58258365</mobile>
</source>

<table>
  <th>  empname    empid   salary   dob </th>
  <td>     john       25825  60000    date</td>
  <td>     joe        25826  70000    date</td>
</table>
```

Every time the `<th>` and `<td>` is changed and the common thing is root element source code. Can anyone help me out to iterate those elements over loop and represent those data over table format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, but the approach of distinct-values doesn't scale well. You best determine the columns upfront, and hardcode like the solution from Tavolo:

```
let $xml := 
  <sources>
    <source>
      <empname>john </empname>
      <empid>25825   </empid>
      <salary> 20000 </salary>
      <dob> 12-08-1993</dob>
    </source>
    <source>
      <empname>joe</empname>
      <empid>25826</empid>
      <salary>20000</salary>
      <dob>12-07-1993</dob>
    </source>
    <source>
      <emptype>developer</emptype>
      <address>3155 </address>
      <mobile>58258365</mobile>
    </source>
    <source>
      <emptype>analyst</emptype>
      <address>3155 </address>
      <mobile>58258365</mobile>
    </source>
  </sources>
let $sources := $xml/source
let $labels := fn:distinct-values($sources/*/fn:node-name(.))
return
  <table>
    <tr>{
      for $label in $labels
      return <th>{ $label }</th>
    }</tr>
    {
      for $source in $sources
      return <tr>{    
        for $label in $labels
        return <th>{ fn:data($source/*[fn:node-name() = $label]) }</th>
      }</tr>
    }
  </table>
```

HTH!

Comment: It's really helpful .How ever i tried to implement this  in my code and  i am getting parser error  :too many elements to retrieve. Could you please help me to specify in some other functionality or modifying this code?

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand your statement. Do you want to be able to combine all such XML files? How about this?

```
<table>
<tr><th>empname</th><th>empid</th><th>salary</th><th>dob</th>   <th>emptype</th></tr>
{for $child in doc("your-file")/source) 
return <tr>{    
return <td>{$child/empname}</td><td>{$child/empid}</td><td>{$child/salary}</td><td>{$child/dob}</td><td>{$child/emptype}</td>
}</tr></table>
```

Comment: The format is right .However ,my table headers are  child elements of source code and  they are not hard coded values . Secondly, my table data are source code's  child element values. i need a generic code . it's just a sample xml format file